# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: while exporting a parquet file from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I am basically trying to export a parquet file inside GCS cloud bucket as shown below in my code which is a GCP cloud function where i am getting error in the line "chunk.to_parquet(parquet_file_path, engine='fastparquet', compression='snappy')" saying -" No such file or directory: 'new_folder_20230206_065500/table1-20230206_065638.parquet". The folder is getting created successfully inside bucket but i am not sure why parquet file is not getting generated inside it.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

def extract_data_to_gcs(request):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=os.getenv('..'),
        user=os.getenv('...'),
        password=os.getenv('...'),
        database='....'
    )

    cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

    tables = ["table1", "table2", "table3"]
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket('data-lake-archive')

    # Create a timestamp-based folder name
    now = datetime.now()
    folder_name = now.strftime("new_folder_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    folder_path = f"{folder_name}/"

    # Create the folder in the GCS bucket
    blob = bucket.blob(folder_path)
    blob.upload_from_string("", content_type="application/octet-stream")

    for table in tables:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table))
        chunks = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table), connection, chunksize=5000000)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            chunk.columns = [str(col) for col in chunk.columns]
            ingestion_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            parquet_file_path = folder_path + f"{table}-{i}.parquet"
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
            # parquet_file_path = folder_path + f'abc.parquet'
            print(f'folder path is {folder_path}')
            print(f'parquet file path is {parquet_file_path}')
            chunk.to_parquet(parquet_file_path, engine='fastparquet', compression='snappy')
            # blob = bucket.blob(folder_path + f'{table}-{i}.parquet')
            # blob.upload_from_filename(folder_path + f'{table}-{i}.parquet')

        cursor.execute("SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.key_column_usage WHERE referenced_table_name = '{}'".format(table))
        referenced_tables = cursor.fetchall()
        for referenced_table in referenced_tables:
            chunks = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {}".format(referenced_table[0]), connection, chunksize=5000000)
            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
                chunk.columns = [str(col) for col in chunk.columns]
                ingestion_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                chunk.to_parquet(f"{folder_path}{referenced_table[0]}-{ingestion_timestamp}-{i}.parquet", engine='fastparquet', compression='snappy')
                blob = bucket.blob(folder_path + f'{referenced_table[0]}-{ingestion_timestamp}-{i}.parquet')
                blob.upload_from_filename(folder_path + f'{referenced_table[0]}-{ingestion_timestamp}-{i}.parquet')

    return 'Data extracted and uploaded to GCS'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to create the folder first? I'm not familiar with Google Cloud, but that might be a cause of the issue. `folder_path = f"{folder_name}/"` Create this folder before doing, `chunk.to_parquet(...)`

Where exactly are the errors thrown? There are two lines with chunk.to_parquet(). Can you reduce the error down to a specific line?

Comment: The error is in first method.. i've update this in the question too....

Comment: yes, folder should get created first then file should get placed inside it... folder is getting created as i said but not the file

Comment: getting same error even after doing folder_path=.... before chunk.to_parquet